# Increment/Decrement Operators not working correctly

Tags: java

I am trying to decrement and increment a value every time a key is pressed, the code looks like working but the c value is not responding correctly.
here's the code:

```
    if (...) {
        ...
    } else if (a == 1) {
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent f) {
                switch (f.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_F:
                        setFullScreen();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        c--;
                        textField.setText("c:" + c);
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                        c++;
                        textField.setText("c:" + c);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in my case, if left is pressed, the value c (which is 1) changes to -2 instead of 0.

Comment: Add some logging to see how many events are actually fired

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 key events per key press, as explained in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Decide which key event you wish to use, then add only the instances that event fires, say on the KEY_PRESSED event.

Comment: This is *closer* to an answer.  If you expound upon it, it might be better than what you have here (which is effectively a comment).

Comment: @Makoto you are correct, that should have been a comment. I think he should be able to work the rest out from there now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use keyReleased instead of the keyPressed. This way the event will fire only 1 time.

The keyPressed Event will be fired while your key is pressed (even if you just press and release it quickly, several KeyEvents will be fired). If you bind the increase/decrease to "keyReleased" it will only fire when the key is released after pressing, therefore only 1 incrementation will occur.

Also everytime the if-statement is executed, a new KeyListener is added to the frame Object. This will result in multiple increase/decrease operations.

Comment: Would this be the right behavior if I held down the key and only had the event update *exactly* once?

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: i have changed the code from KeyPressed to KeyReleased but the problem still occurs. In this case too  ,if i release the key, the value of c changes in the exact same way as KeyPressed. The actual strange thing about my case is that the increment/decrement  operator is following a strange "pattern": if i repetely press RIGHT (which is c++) the value starts from 1 and goes up to 2, then 4, then 7,11,17... same for the LEFT 1,0,-5,-7,-9,-14...

Comment: I just tested it and it worked fine (just as in my explanation). Is there any chance, that the if statement in your sample code is executed several times? If so, then the error is maybe caused by creating too many keyListeners. (Everytime a==1, a new KeyListener will be added to the frame).

Well, as I said, I just tried the same code (except the if statement) and it's working fine for me.

Comment: that was it! ty for ur help!.

Comment: you're welcome. I edited my answer, so that people with similiar issues will have it easier to find the actual problem.